# How to check which string resource of a ListItem in a ListView was clicked?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, uwp-navigation, uwp-c#

Is there a way to check the string resource of ListView item click rather than index of the ListView (which is often demonstrated in tutorials)? 
e.g. I have a `ListView` with 3 items: "Item A", "Item B" and "Item C". If the string resource of the clicked `ListView` item is "Item A", do something.

**MainPage class**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private List<ListItemMain> mainItems;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        gridItemMains = MainItemManger.GetGridItems();
    }

    private void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

**Item class**

```
public class ListItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class BookManger
    {
        public static List<Book> GetListItems()
        {
            var resourceLoader = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView();

            var items = new List<Book>
            {
                new Book { Name = resourceLoader.GetString("ItemA") },
                new Book { Name = resourceLoader.GetString("ItemB") },
                new Book { Name = resourceLoader.GetString("ItemC") }
            };

            return items;
        }
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<Page
    x:Class="My_App.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:data="using:My_App.Models"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind listItems}" ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:ListItem">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Book}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
</Page>
```

Comment: You can access `ClickedItem` property of `ItemClickEventArgs` and Cast it to your `Book` object and from there you can check the Name. Is there any reason you are not using DataBinding? It would be much easier if you were using DataBinding.

Comment: Could you not use Binding to `SelectedItem`?

Comment: That is what I'm using. Not seen any tutorial with example code on this.

Comment: I don't know the correct way to use that.

Comment: Post full XAML, so that I understand how you are setting DatacContext, etc. Normally, you would just do `SelectedItem={Binding SelectedBook}` on your ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `IsItemClickEnabled` property to true to get `ItemClick` event from the `ListView`.

Refer to docs page for [ItemClick Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.itemclick?view=winrt-19041).

Here is the updated XAML would look like:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind listItems}" ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick" IsItemClickEnabled="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:ListItem">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Book}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And the event handler code:

```
void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: Add your code by accessing e.ClickedItem here
}
```

Comment: @MacaronLover, you just need to one more thing in Suresh's code. Check if the item clicked is item A in the SelectionChanged handler. Like '  if (book.Name.Equals("Item A"))  ' Then you could do what you want when the specific item is clicked.

Comment: @MacaronLover updated answer as per previous comment.

Comment: Why the `SelectionChanged` handle rather than the `ItemClick` handler?

Comment: @MacaronLover updated my answer to use `ItemClick` instead of `SelectionChanged`